# What is the difference between map<string, pair<string, foo*>> and map<string, pair<string, foo&>>?

Tags: c++, reference, stl, std

I write a abstract class `foo`, and `bar` class inherits from foo.

I want create a map container that is `map<string, pair<string, foo&>>`, but I cannot compile successfully. The compiler tells me

```
“std::pair<std::string,foo &>::pair”: not appropriate default constructor
```

Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
public:
    virtual void t() = 0;
};

class bar :public foo
{
public:
    void t()
    {
        cout << "bar" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    bar b;
    //wrong
    //map<string, pair<string, foo&>> t;
    //pair<string, foo&> p("b", b);
    //t["t"] = p;

    //right
    map<string, pair<string, foo*>> t;
    pair<string, foo*> p("b", &b);
    t["t"] = p;
    p.second->t();
}
```

I want to know the difference between `map<string, pair<string, foo*>>` and `map<string, pair<string, foo&>>`.

Comment: Do you know what the difference is between a pointer and a reference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux could you detail explain the reason？

Comment: @Lens I'm not sure I understand. You want me to explain the reason for what exactly?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry, I'm not good at english. I want hope you explain that why I must use foo*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first example (which you labeled "wrong") is the line `t["
t"] = p;`. If you look at the documentation for [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) you will find the following passage :

> - value_type must be EmplaceConstructible from std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(key), std::tuple<>().

This implies that your `mapped_type` (in this case, `foo&`) must be default constructible. However, references must *always* refer to an existing object, they can't be default constructed. The example that uses pointers is fine because pointers don't have that restriction.

You can use references as the `mapped_type` but you will have to avoid `operator[]`. For example, you can find an element with [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) or insert one with [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace). The following example compiles fine :

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct foo {};

int main()
{
    foo b;
    //wrong
    map<string, pair<string, foo&>> t;
    pair<string, foo&> p("b", b);
    t.emplace("t", p);
}
```